# Webscrape value from my webpage and store in database SQlite

Tags: python, database, sqlite, web-scraping

I want to webscrape a value from my webpage and send it to a SQlite database every 5 minutes
I have done the webscrape python:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = "http://ludvikasegel.com/wx/cloudbase.asp"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
molnbas = soup.find_all("div", class_="cloudbase")
print (molnbas[0].text.strip())
```

Now I'm stucked how to store it in a SQlite database.
In my database I want the value and a some timestamp.
Any suggestions how to do it or any good simple tutorials?

Thanx

I have checked some tutorials but am still unsure how to do it.

Comment: What format do you want your data to be in? Databases have tables with rows and columns. What would the rows be in your case?

Comment: why are you scraping data from your own site? If you want to know about python sqlite3 [here is the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) and for [this is for SQL in general](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)

Answer (score 1):

First make a `schema.sql` file. This can in theory be put directly into `init_db.py` but it's (in my opinion) good practise to separate it out for clarity.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name;

CREATE TABLE table_name (
    value INTEGER,
    timestamp TEXT
);
```

Then make an `init_db.py` file

```py
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as con, open("schema.sql") as f:
    con.executescript(f.read())
```

Add this to your script that is run every 5th minute.

```py
import datetime 

desired_value = molnbas[0].text.strip()
timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()  # UTC timestamp, change to whatever you want

with sqlite3.connect("database.db") as sqlite_connection:
    sqlite_connection.execute(
        "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (?, ?)",
        (desired_value, timestamp)
    )
```